# Token authentication- "The form has become outdated" and rules issues

Tags: forms, rules, users, privatemsg

I'm using the [Token Authentication](https://drupal.org/project/tokenauth) and [Privatemsg](https://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) modules together.  When a user receives an e-mail notification that they he/she has received a private message, I have placed a link (using a token provided by the Tokenauth module in a query string) that allows the user to log in and see the message.

At the bottom of the page is the message reply form.  I would like the user to be able to reply via this form as well (without logging in, via token authentication).  However, when I tested this, I received the following error:

> The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below
>   and then reload this page.

A Google search revealed [this helpful comment on drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1383918#comment-6226674):

> So it seems you would have to either
>
> unset($form['#token']) or $form['#token'] = NULL

Privatemsg has two message creation forms, the new message form and the reply to message form.

To fix the new message form, I added `unset($form['#token']);` to `hook_form_privatemsg_new_alter()` (new messages) and `hook_form_privatemsg_form_reply_alter()` (replies). I tested this and new private messages as well as replies can now be sent.

I then [disabled caching for the privatemsg module](http://ward.vandewege.net/blog/2009/04/drupal-disable-caching-for-an-entire-module/) so that the messages would always be refreshed.

However, I have a rule that is set to **Show a message on the site** ("Your message was sent to User X!") whenever a private message or reply is sent; this rule is not triggered when a private message is sent if the user is authenticated via Tokenauth even though the private message is saved to the database properly and displayed upon page refresh.

How can I make sure rules are still triggered when authenticated via Tokenauth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, it would seem Rules are not being triggered at all. You could, however, try invoking a rule manually by placing a [rules_invoke_event()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.module/function/rules_invoke_event/7) call within inside a custom form submit function.

Note that the [`#submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) property on Drupal forms allow multiple submit handlers to be called for a single form.

In the `hook_form_privatemsg_new_alter()` and `hook_form_privatemsg_form_reply_alter()` form alters you have implemented you should be able to find and modify the `#submit` property. Just do something like:

```
// Implementation of hook_form_FORMID_alter().
patricks_form_privatemsg_new_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
  $form['#submit'][] = 'patricks_privatemsg_submit';
  return $form;
}
```

Then in your submit handler you can use the rules_invoke_event():

```
function patricks_privatemsg_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
   // Pass parameters for the variables provided by this event, as defined in hook_rules_event_info()...
   rules_invoke_event('privmsg_foo_rule', $foos, $barf, $bam);
}
```

If for some reason you get a rules_invoke_event() function not found error, just add a [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) to your submit handler before invoking the rule.

Comment: Thanks, good solution.  I ultimately moved to using Login One Time module instead of Tokenauth since this provides users with more security (login links expire, whereas tokens are forever).